# object TemplatesPlugin is not a member of package securesocial.controllers

Tags: java, scala, playframework, view, securesocial

I am trying to implement my custom View with secure social

```
 "ws.securesocial" % "securesocial_2.11" % "3.0-M3",
```

But I am getting some error:

```
object TemplatesPlugin is not a member of package securesocial.controllers
```

So I visit the github project and found there is no TemplatesPlugin

https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/3.0-M3/module-code/app/securesocial/controllers

```
package app.com.myApp.plugin;

import play.api.mvc.{RequestHeader, Request};
import play.api.templates.Html;
import securesocial.controllers.TemplatesPlugin;
import securesocial.core.{SecuredRequest, SocialUser};
import play.api.data.Form;
import securesocial.core.SecureSocial._;
import securesocial.controllers.PasswordChange.ChangeInfo;


class MyViews(application: App) extends TemplatesPlugin {

  override def getLoginPage[A](implicit request: Request[A], form: Form[(String, String)],
                               msg: Option[String] = None): Html =
  {
    views.html.Secure.login(form, msg)
  }
  //...
  }
```

and my play.plugins

```
1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
9997:app.com.myApp.plugin.MyViews
```

Then How I go further, What to change?

Answer (score 1):

The module does not use Play plugins any more.  All what used to be a plugin is now a service that needs to get configured in the RuntimeEnvironment for your app.

Check out the sample apps to see how they provide their environments.  You will need to override the viewTemplates attribute to use your custom views.